# How can I validate array field in React Hook Form with the useFieldArray hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-hook-form

I have some questions regarding react hook form and the way it validates the array fields.

I was trying to register the array field with `useEffect` when the component mounts but then I noticed there is a `useFieldArray` hook which is not mounting anything until you append a field.

So I have this:

```js
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray<FieldValues>({
    name: `logic.${index}.questions` as 'logic.0.questions',
  })
```

And I am able to see that field until the select element hits the `onChange` event.

```js
<Select onChange={e => append({ id: e.target.value }) }>...</Select>
```

And depending on what I append, the `fields` value from `useFieldArray` starts to grow its length so I am able to render new things based on that, like:

```js
<Box>
  { fields.map((field) => <Text key={field.id}>{ field.id }</Text> )}
</Box>
```

So for example here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-nested-arrays-x7btr?file=/src/index.js

How would you validate on submit, that the array has a positive length (> 0) and show an error message.

I noticed you can do that easily when the fields are only objects, but what can I do to validate for example if the code I posted here using `useFieldArray`, if the `fields` length is more than 0 then submit the form, otherwise show an error (?)

Answer (score 1):

There's a recent new feature in [react-hook-form v7.34.0](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.34.0) that provides this kind of validation out of the box...

You set it up when you define the field array

In your case, you want the rule `required: true`

```
useFieldArray({
  name: 'test',
  rules: {
    required: true,
  }
})
```

And then you check for/use the error as such

```
errors?.test?.root?.message
```

Note, there is another variant that allows you to provide a custom error message if the required check fails...

e.g.

```
rules: {
  required: {
    value: true,
    message: "At least one is required",
  }
}
```

See here for further details...

https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/

https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/6879

https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/pull/8562

Answer (score 0):

It might not be exactly what you're looking for but here's how I solved it.
I have a similar setup as in the codesandbox you shared, just without nested fields and including a `Remove` button that will remove the last `fieldArray` element when clicked:

```
<button onClick={() => controlledFields.length > 1 ? remove(controlledFields.length - 1) : null}>
  Remove
</button>
```

This is quite important, because I'm using `required:true` validation within `fieldArray.map()`, forcing the user to remove empty input fields and filling at least the first one. In your provided example this would be

```
<Box>
  { 
    fields.map((field) => (
      <>
      <Text 
        key={field.id}
        {...register(`fields.${index}`, {required:true})}
       >
      { field.id }
      </Text> 
      { errors.fields?.[index] && 
          <p> { index === 0 ? "Must select at least one" : "Remove empty fields if unused" } </p>
      }
      </>
    ))
  }
</Box>
```